# Prefil date from database in Jquery UI datepicker field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an edit form, where the values are populated from the database. I have one `date` field in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. I have setup the [jQuery Datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) and its working on the date field, however, when the form first loads, the date field is empty even though the input type has a value from the database, when I checked the HTML source.

How can I make my date field display the date from the database?

EDIT:

I want my input values to be visible in the text field rather than grabbing the values from database and again inserting it into a jQuery/javascript variable/function(default date, showbefore what not).

What can I do to disable `datepicker` from hiding my values in the first place? and only replace the values if I click and choose a date.

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="text" id="date" name="reg_date" value="2012-01-30" />
```

The actual code is in PHP where the value is being retrieved from database and inserted in the value field. The values are correctly generated and inserted because I verified it by looking at the HTML source in firefox.

**Datepicker setting:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
});
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
    $( "#date" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
});
```

Comment: shows the settings datepicker function and as you print in the input

Comment: when you create the datepicker in your code, use the "beforeShow" method to pass your initialization date value to the datepicker.  so do something like this: $('.selector').datepicker({
   beforeShow: function(input, inst) { ... }
});   reference: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShow   BTW: it would help to see some code so we know how things are defined presently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change for this:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",                 
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

if your browser has cached ... press CTRL + F5

Comment: After a lot of searching, I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200290/jquery-date-picker-doesnt-show-original-text-value/8200551#8200551 , which incidentally is the same as yours, although the date format needs to be `yy-mm-dd` and not `dd-mm-yy` for my requirement, changing to which, I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker is over-writing value. I would suggest you trigger datepicker when focused on date field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default date in the datepicker settings code.

Example: `$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +7 });` to set the default date as 7 days from now.

True story.

Comment: I don't want to do that. The field has nothing to do with today's date. The date is retrieved from the database and it should be displayed in the input field without the `datepicker` plugin removing it.

Am sure your answer can be tweaked to exactly what I need, but that's too much work for something that should be very simple.

Comment: Post your current uiPicker settings. And the HTML and PHP code you use to display the date.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now you have posted your code it is very obvious.

Your database date format is YYYY-MM-DD
Your jQuery UI format is yy-mm-dd 
See what's wrong? Your missing at least 2 digits of the year.

To fix this, simply enter the correct format in your code.

Example:

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy" });
$( "#date" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy" );
```

Comment: jQuery's `yy-mm-dd` corresponds to the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

When you use `yyyy` it gives u `20122012`, i.e. two times the year.